# Assignment in Unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static-variables

I want to develop an experimental program in unity. In the program, I use scripts to create a series of objects and assign values to them. I use Tobii's SDK to develop an eye movement experimental program. In order to get the line of sight feedback of these objects (actually a ray collision detection principle), I created a script and added this script for each object. But when I run, I find that only the last of the series of objects I create will give correct feedback, and the other objects will not give feedback。
My feedback script is as follow:

```cs
void Update () {

        if (_gazeAwareComponent.HasGazeFocus) {
            img.color = _outColor;
            newText = textName.text;
            MainInteraction.isEnter = true;

        } else {
            img.color = initinalColor;
            newText = null;
            MainInteraction.isEnter = false;
        }
        
    }
```

I use a static variable to control the state of feedback.
And in my main script, my fuction is:

```cs
void createTargetAndText (int number) {
        int[] a = GetRandomSequence(10, currentTrailTime);
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            GameObject image = new GameObject();
            image.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            image.name = a[i].ToString();
            image.AddComponent<Image>();
            image.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
            image.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius = targetSize / 2;
            image.AddComponent<Feedback>();
            image.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sourceImage;
            image.transform.SetParent(currentGameObject.transform.GetChild(3).transform);
            image.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");

            GameObject textGame = new GameObject();
            textGame.name = a[i].ToString();
            textGame.AddComponent<Text>();
            textGame.GetComponent<Text>().font = textFont;
            textGame.GetComponent<Text>().text = textGame.name;
            textGame.GetComponent<Text>().fontSize = 48;
            textGame.GetComponent<Text>().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
            textGame.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.black;
            textGame.transform.SetParent(image.transform);
            textGame.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");
        }
    }
```

The only problem is `MainInteration.isEnter` doesn't work, when I try to change the color to debug, it works.

```
if (_gazeAwareComponent.HasGazeFocus) {
            img.color = _outColor;
            newText = textName.text;
            MainInteraction.isEnter = true;

            if (this.name == "2") {
                MainInteraction.isEnter = true;
                img.color = Color.cyan;
            }
        }
```

I guess the problem may come from:

- the static variables in Unity.

Can someone help me answer it? Thank you

Comment: static means there is only one.  If your code needs to track the `isEnter` value for each Feedback script, then this won't work because there is only one isEnter variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I see what you mean. I'll try

Comment: The problem has been solved. It's really what you said. Thank you again